# Retrieve last entry for each

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table for evaluating students:

```
StudentID | EvaluationStatusID| Date
1011010   |      1            |2013-11-07 20:31:51.000
1011020   |      1            |2013-11-08 13:23:51.000
1011010   |      2            |2013-11-08 20:31:51.000
1011020   |      3            |2013-11-09 20:31:51.000
```

The evaluation of a student does through different stages - 'submitted','assessed,'accepted' etc.

I need to get the LATEST record(by date) on each student in teh form 'StudentID-EvaluationStatusID'.

So,in the above data i should have the following returned:

```
1011010-2
1011020-3
```

In Sql server 2008,how do I get this?

Comment: Where is  student with id = 1011020?

Comment: my mistake - editted the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is using ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT StudentID, EvaluationStatusID, Date,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID
                                   ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM dbo.Student
)
SELECT StudentID, EvaluationStatusID, Date
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4bb1/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT StudentID +' ' +EvaluationStatusID
    FROM tblTable T
    WHERE T.Date = (SELECT MAX(TT.Date) 
                    FROM tblTable TT
WHERE TT.StudentID  = T.StudentID  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 With S1 as
    (
    select StudentID +''+EvaluationStatusID as Info, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID
                                       ORDER BY StudentID) as RC
     from students 
     )
     select * from S1 where S1.RC in (Select MAX(S1.RC)from S1)
     Group By Info, RC
```